# NPV Formula returns a #NUM error because the date and value ranges contain blank formulas

Tags: excel, formula, finance

dataset (dates and values)

[image]

formula:

```
=XNPV(F4,$B$8:$B$1048576,$A$8:$A$1048576)
```

Comment: `The series of values must contain at least one positive value and one negative value.` from: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xnpv-function-1b42bbf6-370f-4532-a0eb-d67c16b664b7

Comment: Hi Scott, the issue is below the data values there is this formula that results in a blank:
=IF($D$3="Monthly",IFERROR(IF(EOMONTH(A43+1,0)=EOMONTH($D$5+1,0),"",EOMONTH(A43+1,0)),""),IFERROR(IF(YEAR(A43)=YEAR($D$5),"",EDATE(A43,12)),""))